# In a normal Blockchain(NOT Cryptocurrency) implementation, what determines the time and processing power needed to successfully mine a node?

Tags: resources, blockchain

So I am thinking of an idea using the blockchain technology, but before I start with it I need to know how much resources will my client(s) will need to mine a node, how much time, and what factors contribute to it.

I know that in the `Cryptocurrency` domain, `difficulty` is an important factor, but it will play no role in mine, so I was wondering if anyone could shed some light onto this.

Answer (score 0):

Difficulty is a property of the blockchain, not cryptocurrencies. You will not be able to write any blockchain applications without it.

In a traditional Proof of Work blockchain, you're basically speaking of three intrinsically related variables:

- network size: total computational power of the entire network (every node)
- difficulty: how "hard" the proof of work problem is to solve
- block frequency: how many new blocks are found per unit of time

The way these are related are as follows: if the network size grows, but the difficulty does not, then naturally many more blocks will be found per unit of time. If the difficulty grows, and the network size stay constant, then the block frequency will decrease.

For Bitcoin, they are trying to maintain a constant block frequency, which is why the difficulty is adjusted according to the network size. But once again, this is a fundamental property of **blockchains**, so you will have to consider it regardless of your application.

Comment: So, say if I keep a constant difficulty, say `k`, that works right?

Answer (score 0):

You're considering the use of a blockchain implementation but are concerned about the resources required for the peers in the network to come to consensus.

What you're referring to is the consensus mechanism.  BTC uses Proof of Work as it's consensus mechanism and it turns out that's as expensive and time consuming as it is effective.  There are a number of consensus mechanisms you might look into: Proof of Elapsed Time (POET), Yet Another Consensus (YAC), Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance (PBFT).  Depending on your implementation you may want to look at these mechanisms with a public or private blockchain implementation.  The outcome you want and the resources necessary to get there will determine your consensus mechanism.